# Firestore security rule: Null value error when using Set.hasAny()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a `user` collection with two fields `memberOf` and `managerOf` (that is, of an organisation; both are arrays of doc id).

I would like to restrict a manager to list only users that are members of an organisation they managed.

In JS, it would be something like this:

```js
const memberOf = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const managerOf = [6, 7, 1, 9, 0]

console.log(memberOf.some(el => managerOf.includes(el))) //  returns true
```

This is what I have so far:

```js
function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth.uid != null
}

function isAdmin() {
    return isSignedIn() && 'admin' in request.auth.token && request.auth.token.admin
}

match /users/{userId} {
    allow get: if isSignedIn() && (request.auth.uid == userId || isAdmin());
    allow list: if isAdmin() || ???; //  how can I express the above condition?
    allow write: if isAdmin();
}
```

And that's the query:

```js
const unsubscribe = db.collection('users')
    .where('memberOf', 'array-contains', organisationId)
    .orderBy('email', 'asc')
    .onSnapshot(snap => {
        console.log(`Received query snapshot of size ${snap.size}`)
        var docs = []
        snap.forEach(doc => docs.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
        actions.setMembers(docs)
    }, error => console.error(error))
```

First, I wanted to use the `organisationId` from the request in the security rule, but it's not available as it's not a write operation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#resource)

I thought about:

```js
function hasMemberManagerRelationship(userId) {
    return isSignedIn() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)).data.memberOf in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.managerOf
}

match /users/{userId} {
    allow get: if isSignedIn() && (request.auth.uid == userId || isAdmin());
    allow list: if isAdmin() || hasMemberManagerRelationship(userId);
    allow write: if isAdmin();
}
```

or

```js
function hasMemberManagerRelationship(userId) {
    return isSignedIn() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)).data.memberOf.toSet().hasAny(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.managerOf.toSet())
}
```

(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Set#hasAny)

But it's not working and I have the error `FirebaseError: Null value error. for 'list' @ L27`. AND on top of that, that could generate a lot of extra read operations (not billing-wise optimised).

I could do something like the following:

```js
allow list: if isAdmin() || (isManagerOf('jJXLKq7p9wWSNLsHcVIn') && 'jJXLKq7p9wWSNLsHcVIn' in resource.data.memberOf);
```

where `jJXLKq7p9wWSNLsHcVIn` is the id of an organisation (and used in the query), but I don't know how I can retrieve the id from the request "context"..

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Ok. First, thank you @Doug Stevenson for mentioning `debug()` in another post! I didn't know it exists, and it rocks!

The result of `debug(resource.data.memberOf)` in the debug log was:

```
constraint_value {
  simple_constraints {
    comparator: LIST_CONTAINS
    value {
      string_value: "jJXLKq7p9wWSNLsHcVIn"
    }
  }
}
```

`LIST_CONTAINS` forced me to have a look at List: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAny

<strike>`toSet()` does not apply to a list, but a list has already the `hasAny()` function.</strike>
(in fact, it does exist but it didn't work in my case )

In the end, this rule works:

```js
function hasMemberManagerRelationship() {
    return isSignedIn() && resource.data.memberOf.hasAny(getUser(request.auth.uid).data.managerOf)
}
```

Now I'm just wondering if `getUser(request.auth.uid).data.managerOf` is somehow cached (1 read for multiple user entries) or re-run every time (100 users, 100 extra reads).

**Any thoughts on that?**

I sincerely hope this is the first case ^^

Answer (score 0):

I tested rules which are pretty similar to your attempt using the firestore "Rules Playground" and it seems to be working.
You do not need to `get()` the current `userId` because you already have it in the `resource` object.
I am not sure it would generate a lot more read operations because we are only using `get()` for `request.auth.uid`.

```
    function getUser(userId) {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId));
    }

    function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    function isAdmin() {
        return isSignedIn() && 'admin' in request.auth.token && request.auth.token.admin;
    }

    function hasMemberManagerRelationship() {
        return isSignedIn() && resource.data.memberOf.toSet().hasAny(getUser(request.auth.uid).data.managerOf.toSet());
    }

    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read: if isAdmin() || hasMemberManagerRelationship();
    }
```

Where exactly are you getting the `FirebaseError: Null value error`?

Comment: In firebase emulator.

Comment: I don't see where `userId` is used in your `hasMemberManagerRelationship()` function. You mean to pass `resource` maybe? With your solution I have the following error: `Function not found error: Name: [toSet]`

Comment: I copied it from your question and forgot to remove it, the `userId` wasn't needed (edited now). Does all of your documents have the `memberOf` and `managerOf` fields set, or at least initialized to an empty array?

Comment: "Does all of your documents have the memberOf and managerOf fields set" -> that was not the case and I fixed that, but still getting the error `Function not found error: Name: [toSet]` :-/